# RegEx - Capturing multiple times

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am currently trying to convert an HTML-table like the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some Text
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="..." ...>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Into an HTML-list like that:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p> Some Text </p>
        </div>
        <img src="..." ...>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Since I need to do this in several files (100+) I would like to accomplish it using a regular expression. However, while I am able to catch the parts I am interessted in, it only seems to capture the last occurence of the capture groups.

Is there a way to get all captured parts back?

Here is my current progress:

```
<table>(?>\s*?<tr>\s*?<td>(.*?)<\/td>\s*?<td>.*?(<img[^>]*>).*?<\/td>.*?<\/tr>)+\s*?<\/table>
```

(If you are interrested, here is a link for fiddling around: 
https://regex101.com/r/hQ8pF1/2
)

My editor of choice is Sublime Text (using PCRE engine AFAIK), but I am willing to use anything to approach this task.

Comment: Attempting to do this with regex might prove _very_ challenging, but possible, if you have strict rules for the input. Even more so if you have attributes on those tags (with some of them containing `>` characters, or more complex scenarios). If you have access to a HTML parser, I would most certainly recommend using it, despite performance differences.

Comment: @JánosWeisz thankfully the tables I need to edit seem to be pretty identical (regarding their structure). Thanks for mentioning an HTML parser though, I might take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

`\s*?<tr>\s*?<td>(.*?)<\/td>\s*?<td>.*?(<img[^>]*>).*?<\/td>.*?<\/tr>` w/ `sig` for options should do it.

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/yU8nD5/1).

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps. Is there a way though to also replace the surrounding <table> tags? Or would it be easier to remove them in a second iteration, using a different RegEx of course?

Comment: Yes, I think a separate regex would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html) tool (windows only AFAIK). It supports the regex search-and-replace for multiple files. Matching multiple occurences should be no problem.

And have you tried to match without the "table" around? like this https://regex101.com/r/hQ8pF1/3